# Why does positive definiteness implies positivity on diagnal

Tags: matrices

The title says it all. Why does positive semi definiteness implies positivity on diaginal elements.

Answer (score 3):

If $A = (a_{ij})$ is a positive definite matrix then $v^T A v > 0$ for every vector $v\neq 0$. In particular, $a_{ii} = e_i^T A e_i > 0$, where 
$$e_i=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
\vdots\\
0\\
1\\
0\\
\vdots\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is the vector whose $i$-th coordinate is 1, and all other coordinates are 0.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on $a_{ii} = e_i^T A e_i > 0$. I did not understand it.

Comment: I added the definition of $e_i$ to my answer. Use the definition of matrix multiplication to check that $a_{ii} = e_i^T A e_i$.

Comment: I do not get it, this what my question says. Actually it is just mathematical way of expressing my question. What I would like to know is the proof for this.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on your answer.

Comment: Explain what you don't understand.

Comment: How did you infer $a_{ii} = e_i^T A e_i > 0$

Comment: $a_{ii} = e_i^T A e_i$ by the definition of matrix multiplication; $e_i^T A e_i > 0$ since $A$ is positive definite.